# Show/hide "used" bar and/or entry in Files sidebar for specific drives?

Tags: pantheon-files, mount

I've several partitions on my HDD, the main ones being my elementary OS one which shows up as "File System" in the sidebar, an NTFS data one called "Data", which I've set to auto-mount to /media/data, and "Acer", which holds my Windows stuff. Today I was trying to make ncmpcpp work with a Music folder I had in the Data partition, and the simplest solution seemed to be to mount it to my /home/user/Music, which seemed to work perfectly.

Now, however, when I open the Files application, in the sidebar there's a bit of a mess.

[image: Screenshot of the sidebar]

Now there seem to be two Data drives (is that the correct term to use here? drives?), the top one, with the "this and this full" bar leading to the Music folder, and the bottom one leading to the actual Data partition. I would like for them to either switch places in the list, so that the "full" bar actually corresponds to the drive it is showing the info about (and, label the music one accordingly so it's less confusing), or, preferably, hide the Music folder one from the list entirely while still mounting it to /home/username/Music, such that ncmpcpp still can find my tracks and the sidebar is not cluttered.

EDIT: changed nothing in any settings, but upon opening Files both Data entries now have the bar and are therefore indistinguishable if one does not know the position of each one.

EDIT 2: I mounted the Music folder with adding `/media/data/Music    /home/username/Music    none    bind` to fstab, as was suggested by some ncmpcpp user, then did `sudo mount -a`

Comment: Please provide exact details of the command you used to mount the Music folder in the Data partion to your home Music folder.

Comment: added it to the post @JeremyWootten

Comment: Thanks.  Would it solve the problem if the duplicate device entry were removed?  After all, you can access the music through your home Music folder.

Comment: Yes, it would! @JeremyWootten

Comment: I have just pushed a PR that fixes this here: https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/1403.  In the end, rather than remove the duplicate entry, I renamed it to show where it was actually pointing.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer to this is to get it fixed in the source code so an issue needs to be raised at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues - I will do that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!